# Imagemagick conditional resizing

Tags: java, imagemagick, dynamic-resizing

I want to shrink the images only if they are bigger than the size 300X100 dimension, 
for example:

- If image is 250X200 dimension I want it with 250X100 dimension
- If image is 420X90 I want it with 300X90
- If height or width are greater than  300X100  then only i need to Shrink it
- Otherwise use same height or width

How can I write this type of conditional ImageMagick commands in my Java program? I am writing like this:

```
convert image.jpg -resize 387x97^> image_resized.jpg.
```

but this is not working.

Comment: And where's your Java? This is just a command line. If you put that in Java, it surely won't work because it has output redirection. However, if you start the command shell through Java, with this passed in as the command, that should work.

Comment: I've had to do a fair bit of reformatting to make your question readable. When posting questions, please take a few moments to use bullets and preformatted code - there is help available on the "markdown" syntax.

Comment: this is how  I am executing commands in my java program . just I want one conditional convert command .                                     Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

Answer (score 0):

I would think this would work

```
convert image.jpg -resize 300x100 image_resized.jpg.
```

Comment: i dont  want to stretch images lessthan 300X100 size. above command converts all image irrespective of size.

Comment: command = "convert C:\fb\indiamap_resized.JPG -resize 300x100! ^> C:\fb\indiamap_resized_resized.JPG";                                           Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command); this is not working for me.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in replying but I am new to this and did not see the comments. You can only have one resize option and the choices are on this page http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php#geometry If you want to do something special you will have to use variables for width and height and do some calculations outside the Imagemagick code.